# Hibernate Unknow Column at save() after rename column

Tags: java, hibernate

I had a column `useless_id` in table `foo`. This column is `foreign key` into other table.

I have mapped it like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo{

    @Column(name = "useless_id")
    private Integer uselessId;

    //...

}
```

Everything worked perfect. But I decided to change the name of column `useless_id` into `useful_id`.

After that appear problems. When I try to save an `Foo` object: `session.save(new Foo(...))` I get `Unknown column F.useless_id in 'where clause'`.

The query is printed in console `insert into foo (..., useful_id, ...) value (...)`

In list of columns I don't see `useless_id`.

Why I get `Unknow column useless_id in 'where clause'` ? Why use `where` when `insert`?

It is was changed everywhere. Even in `Foo object`

I get this error only when try to `save`.

UPDATE(`Foo class is Order Class` and `useful_id` is `customer_id`):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;

    @Column(name = "shipping_address")
    private String shippingAddress;

    //setters getters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
public class Customer{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    //setters getters

}
```

This is how I try to insert new object

```
//...
session.beginTransaction();

Order order = new Order();
//set random values. customer_id get valid value, it exists in customers

session.save(order);
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

For `DESCRIBE orders;` command I get:

```
Field----------------Type-----------Null---Key---Default---Extra    
id-------------------int(11)--------NO-----PRI---NULL------auto_increment
status---------------int(50)--------NO-----------NULL------
customer_id----------int(50)--------NO-----MUL---NULL------
shipping_address-----varchar(191)---NO-----------NULL------
```

Comment: what is your ddl-auto setting?

Comment: Look at the database, has the column name changed? If so you have you searched your code for "useless_id" and uselessId? If they are not there, have you tried rebuilding the project in your IDE?

Comment: @mavriksc In `hibernate.cfg.xml` is setted `<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

Comment: @RobertBain In database the column is changed. I rebuilded project but same result.

Comment: Can we see your updated `Foo` entity code please? Also can we see the entity code with the foreign key to `Foo`?

Comment: did you change the xml for the other object? can you add the mapping

Comment: @RobertBain I changed only `@Column(name = "useful_id") private Integer usefulId;` @mavriksc I didn't changed the other object. I changed only column in Foo and database and checked to be sure foreign key still work, and it work.

Comment: Still, I think if we could see the `Foo` class and the class with the foreign key to `Foo` it will help us rule things out.

Comment: @RobertBain @mavriksc I added those two classes into my question. `Foo class` represent `Order class`.

Comment: where is the mapping? @OneToOne ...

Comment: @mavriksc nowhere, because I declared foreign key into mysql and I don't care if I put in java an invalid value. mysql will return back an error if its invalid.

Comment: What is `useless_id` and `useful_id` in the new (real) code?

Comment: And can we see the method that you use to save please?

Comment: @RobertBain I forgot to mention: `useful_id` is `customer_id`.

Comment: @RobertBain I added the code how I try to save.

Comment: What column name are you seeing it try to save to?

Comment: @RobertBain column? I try to save(insert) entire object.

Comment: Can you also log into the mysql database and run `DESCRIBE orders;` and show us the output please?

Comment: I'm asking in the error, you were saying it couldn't find `useless_id`. What the real error, since `useless_id` was just your initial example.

Comment: @RobertBain initial name of `customer_id(useful_id)` was `customers_id(useless_id)`

Comment: @RobertBain I added output from `DESCRIBE orders;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196543/discussion-between-robert-bain-and-kunlun).

Comment: @RobertBain I found the problem. Look at answer. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

It raised from MySQL. I found it by tried to insert with SQL command, direct to MySQL. Same error.

So I was looking very carefully in db and I found the problem is from triggers. In one of triggers still use old name of column.

Now make sense: `Unknow column useless_id in 'where clause'`. That `where clause` was in trigger which try to find `useless_id`, but it no longer exists.

**CONCLUSION: After change name of column, check triggers.**

Comment: Ha! Glad you got to the bottom of it!

Answer (score -3):

In your java class you changes column name from **useless_id** to **userful_id**, but same think you didnt changes in your DB structure due to which you see this error.